# Spring Data + QueryDSL empty predicate + Predicate chaining

Tags: spring, predicate, querydsl

let me get straight to the point.
I am using Spring Data JPA with QueryDSL in a project and I cannot figure out this myself.

I have the QueryDSL predicates in static methods that can take arguments and if the argument is not correct it should return "empty predicate" :

```
public static BooleanExpression byWhateverId(Long whateverId) {
  if(whateverId == null) return [insert magic here];
  // if parameter is OK return usual predicate
  return QClass.property.whateverId.eq(whateverId);
}
```

Now I want to be able to chain these predicates using AND/OR oprators :

```
someRepository.findAll(byWhateverId(someParam).and(bySomethingElseId(1));
```

The problem here is that at this point I don't know whether 'someParam' is null or not (of course I can check but that's a lot of IFs).
I also know I can use BooleanBuilder class but that seems also like a lot of code that should not be needed.

Does anybody knows what could be inserted instead of "[insert magic here]" ???
Or maybe I am missing something somewhere...

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can return null for non matching predicates in `byWhateverId` and `bySomethingElseId` and combine the predicate via `ExpressionUtils.allOf()`

In your case

```
Predicate where = ExpressionUtils.allOf(byWhateverId(someParam), bySomethingElseId(1));
someRepository.findAll(where);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
This looks quite nice but still I would like to chain then without any   additional costs (like using ExpressionUtils).This solution is basically the same as BooleanBuilder.I really like the way of byWhateverId(1).and(bySomethingElseId(1)).
But maybe I am just too strict in this matter and I should accept this :)

Answer (score 13):

4 years old question, but anyway...

You can return sql predicate which is always true, like true=true:

```
public static BooleanExpression alwaysTrue() {
    return Expressions.TRUE.isTrue;
}
```

If you have a bunch of these the generated sql won't be super nice, so you might want to limit such usages to a minimum.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, I completely forgot about this.
The right solution (from my point of view) is to use [BooleanBuilder](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.7/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/BooleanBuilder.html).