# How to query couchbase with multiple values using spring-data-couchbase

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Hi I have an endpoint like `/findBy` and it can take several query params similar like ;

```
findBy?color="blue"&size="big"&city="ny"&country="usa"
```

How can I have such query in repository layer using spring-data-couchbase. Normally if it would something like `findByCity` or `findByColor` only I would have such methods in my repository

```
@Repository
public interface HouseRepository  extends CouchbaseRepository<House, String> {

    House findByColor(String Color);
    House findByCity(String City);
}
```

but in this case I might not get all the parameter values. I want to query whatever values I have. Same `findBy` should return the values in these cases:

```
findBy?country="usa"
findBy?city="ny"&country="usa"
findBy?color="blue"&size="big"
```

Can such thing be done using spring data couchbase **without** writing custom sql queries?

Answer (score 2):

###### You can use [`Querydsl Extension.`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)

Querydsl is a framework that enables the construction of statically typed SQL-like queries through its fluent API.

You have `QueryDSL` integration, [you can derive queries from the attributes contained in a `Request` query string.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe)

Please see these links for more information:

- [Spring Data Extensions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions)
- [How to easy implement 'REST API query language' with Querydsl and Spring Data to filter the entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127468/how-to-easy-implement-rest-api-query-language-with-querydsl-and-spring-data-to)
- [Spring Data + QueryDSL empty predicate + Predicate chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090122/spring-data-querydsl-empty-predicate-predicate-chaining)